# Can VGG 19 fine-tuned model outperform Inception -V3 fine-tuned model?

Tags: deep-learning, floating-accuracy, pre-trained-model

I am using pre-trained and fine-tuned models for cell classification. The images were not seen before by any of the transfer learning models. In the process, I found that a fine-tuned VGG19 model outperforms the fine-tuned Inception-V3 mode though both these models are trained on the ImageNet data. What contributes to this difference? is it because of the model architecture?

Comment: One reason may be VGG19 model was not as 'over-fitted' as the 'inception-V3' model on the ImageNet data.